# How to manufacture cheap custom flexible circuit boards? (strips)

Tags: flexible, fpc

Let's suppose I need two long series of IR emitters and receivers to detect position of people along a hallway (corridor). I would use surface mount components to make the sensors less noticeable, and one series per side of the hallway. This is only the framework, no need to suggest improvements here :)

I could order custom PCBs online, but the thickness would be significant and I would have to run wires all the way to each PCB.

Another solution is to produce some custom plastic strips with metallic traces, on which I would solder directly the components.

Only one emitter and only at most three receivers would be active at the same time, the expected current consumption is 500 mA, at most 1 A (this if the IR emitters are pushed a lot), therefore metallic traces on plastic could work.

I have experience with the plastic circuit of the dashboard of my old ('90s) car and it was able to carry enough current to light the dashboard bulbs. I also successfully soldered stuff on it, without the circuit melting or deforming. See attached image (found online) as example of what plastic strips I mean.

[image: plastic strip]

However, I was not able to find any means to produce said plastic strips. How could I get them? I would need a periodic design, repeated over and over along the strip. I would say 10 mm width by 20 metres length (2x 10 m).

Answer (score 1):

There are PCB manufacturers that offer flexible PCBs. However, PCBs which are some meters long will cost a significant amount of money.
You may look into a conductive silver paint (e.g. http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/electrically-conductive-silver-paint-n36ba). With that you can "paint" your electrical traces onto a thin substrate.

Comment: I cannot paint manually 10m times the number of traces... But I wonder: LED strips are super cheap, would it be expensive to have a similar flexible PCB made on request?

Comment: You can find it out yourself: http://www.elecrow.com/premium-pcb-service-p-1061.html

Comment: @OlafM LED strips are cheap because they manufacture that flex tape pcb in hundred kilometer quantities. If you want a custom flex its pricey. If you want that exact same flex pcb as used in the LED strips its sold wholesale (unpopulated) for a few cents a foot at qty

Comment: @crasic not for this project, but that could be an idea too in other cases, nowadays there are LED strips with 4 or more independent lines on them, sometimes they may be enough (two-wire interface for example).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make something yourself.

I'm assuming the components are several cm apart, and the components are hence a small fraction of the overall length.

Use small, simple, PCB's for the components. Their would likely be an emitter PCB and a receiver PCB.

Then use [adhesive copper tape](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1128) for conductors between component PCBs.
AFAIK, that adhesive wouldn't conduct well enough for your application, so it would need to be removed with some kind of solvent. I believe I've seen narrower copper strip with non-conductive adhesive. Thick aluminium foil might work too.

The copper strip might be soldered onto the PCBs, though I'd expect that to be quit hard unless the strip is quite short, so it may need a mechanical fixing or maybe silver-loaded epoxy.

EDIT:
I believe companies on, e.g. Alibaba, have 2mm copper tape on e.g. adhesive-backed PET.

However I don't know if they sell in quantities small enough to be useful.

I hadn't thought of stacking layers, mainly because I thought connecting it to the components might be awkward.

Comment: I suppose you mean I should stack several layers of that tape, one for every power or signal line, right? good idea anyway

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'stack'. I was thinking of replicating the structure of a single sided PCB. Yes with strips for the same purpose as a flexible PCB. I *think* I saw that conductive tape in 2mm wide, which might be narrow enough.

Comment: If you saw it 2 mm wide, then I understand your idea. Given the 6 mm width, I though the point was to stack layers, one per trace.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate our comments

Answer (score 0):

The problem with PCB prototyping services is that "unusual" tends to imply "expensive". There are plenty of services out that that will make flexible PCBs on kapton substrates but they aren't cheap.

The economics are very different for mass production. The cost per unit of PCBs drops massively as volume increases.